# Boas práticas com $.get do jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, front-end

Acredito que não seja recomendado fazer um `$.get` dentro de um `$.get`.

Mas então qual seria a melhor prática para este código abaixo:

```
var valorSalario = getSalarioAtual(location.state);

$.getJSON('https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=?').done (function(location) {

    if (salarioNacional(location.state)) {
        $("#salarioatual").html("Salário Mínimo Nacional <br/> R$" + this.valorSalario);
    } else {
        $("#salarioatual").html("Salário do seu estado (" + location.state + "): <br/> R$ 880.00");
    }
});

function getSalarioAtual(estado) {
    var estado = getSiglaEstado(estado);
    var salario = "";
    $.get('/salarios-estado/' + estado).done(function(response){
       salario = response.salario;
       return salario;
    });
}
```

Qual seria a melhor implementação para essa solução? Desde já, Agradeço.

Comment: Você precisa fazer as duas chamadas em paralelo ou uma após a outra?

Comment: uma após a outra, já tenho que está com a variável valorSalario preenchida para usar dentro da outra requisição..

Comment: Não vejo problemas em chamar um `GET` dentro de outro, pois dessa forma, você garante que o resultado da primeira chamada, será passado como parâmetro para a segunda chamada. Isso é bem comum, eu já utilizei dessa forma.

Comment: Lembrando que dessa forma um `GET` não está sendo chamado dentro de outro, e sim sequencial.

Comment: Usar `location` como nome de variável desaconselho pois é uma global de `window`. O que é `this.valorSalario`, e confirmas que ambos os `GET`  têm como ponto de partida o `location.state`?